# Divergence on tensor product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, differentiation

[image]

Can someone explain how first equation can be expanded as third equation?
I'm familiar with vector calculus, but not so familiar with tensor calculus, though I know all the definitions. 
I don't have any reliable textbook for that.
Thank you.

Comment: $F$ carries no indices (since $p\rho$ doesn't), so the tensor product can only be meant as $\vec v\otimes\vec  v = \vec v^2 = |\vec v|^2$ in my opinion...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that I didn't explained the symbols... T (looks like F) is a stress tensor and on the second line it's Pg, Pressure multiplied by metric tensor.

Comment: @Photon: If $T$ carries no indices, how does one take the dot product and equate that with a vector in $\mathbf v$?

Comment: @KyleKanos: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: @Heptacle: In this case, disregard my comment, please.

Comment: @Photon: The first one...

Comment: @KyleKanos: Well, you could interpret the nabla as a gradient of the scalar function F which gives a vector like the first term of the equation. The dot would be a rather unusual notation, you are right, but not more unusual than the tensor product being the dot product, as I assumed it. I guess, my biggest problem was reading the metric tensor as a scalar function. ;)

Comment: @Photon: If you had ever seen any fluid dynamics previously, you would never ever make any of those mistakes....

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  This is easiest to prove using explicit indices.  Putting in the indices, the stress tensor is
$$
T_{ij} = P \delta_{ij} + \rho v_i v_j.
$$
The divergence of this quantity is then:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} T_{ij} = \sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( P \delta_{ij} + \rho v_i v_j \right),
$$
and these coordinate derivatives act normally on the quantities in brackets:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} T_{ij} = \sum_i \left[ P \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \delta_{ij} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} \delta_{ij} + v_j v_i \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_i} + \rho v_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} v_i + \rho v_i \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_i} v_j \right]
$$
The first of these terms vanishes, and the remaining terms correspond to the four terms in the third line of your equation.